# Email is not delivered and code results in internal server error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have code to send message via php mailer to my email address.

I get server error but i don't receive any message on inbox or spam folder.

Please help and , and this is my code

```
<?php
require_once("class.phpmailer.php"); 
include("class.smtp.php"); 
try {
$sname= "moda"; // 
$smail="nase25r@yahoo.com"; // sender email
$rname="anyone"; // 
$rmail="nalshlwan@kacst.edu.sa"; // receiver email
$sub="supject"; 

$body="ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"; 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "TLS";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = ""; // my gmil email
$mail->Password = ""; // my gmail password
$mail->AddReplyTo($smail,$sname); 
$mail->AddAddress($rmail, $rname); 
$mail->From = $smail; 
$mail->FromName = $sname; 
$mail->Subject = $sub; 
$mail->MsgHTML($body); 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
if($mail->Send()) {
echo "Done";
}
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: from you condition if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Done";
} it is clear that if email is not sent it will echo "done" so there seems some issue with your mail sending part. check with hosting as well

Comment: [**From what I can see you are trying to send a TLS thru the SSL port instead of 587 which is the TLS port.**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en) Would also recommend you to use `$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');`

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Done";
}
```

This means that if mail is not send, it will echo out Done. Change the condition to:

```
if($mail->Send())
{
    echo "Done";
}
else
{
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Now you will see the error message

Comment: Sorry, but this should have been posted as a comment, since it does _not_ answer the real issue here, but just a symptom.